# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints after transform project from objective-c to swift

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints

How can it be possible, that an app, that runs in objective-c without problems, get the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"-error after moving it to swift?

I´ve only copied the views of an app to a swift-project and now get this error. But when the constraints are valid in objective-c, how is it possible, that they are invalid in swift???

This is the view, I want to display:

[image]

When all fields are filled as in the screenshot, now error appears.
The error only is thrown when **one or more fields are empty**!

This are the contraints of this view

[image]

The constraints are the same as in the objective-c-Version...

What might i show u more, Mr Beardsley?

**I uploaded the swift-Project to [here](http://www.filedropper.com/visitenkarten)**

**u can  find the objective-c-version (very large!) [here](http://www.filedropper.com/visitenkartenobjectivec)**

to get the error, u must go this way:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not possible. Your Swift project has different constraints than your Objective-C project. You just haven't figured out what constraints are different and where they are coming from.

Comment: We could probably help more if you put some actual code or projects up for people to look at.

Comment: how can i put code or projects up? plz help me!

Comment: mark the code in a certain file copy and paste it here

Comment: @rob mayoff: you´re right! Found it :-) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Rob Mayoff was right: my Swift project has different constraints than my Objective-C project. :-(